# Why doesn't the AppBar appear?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a navigation drawer app which it's first screen is a Map Fragment.
On Lollipop and above it displays the app correctly, however on KitKat and below, the AppBar is completely covered by the map.

Here's my app's style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

The fragment container is on the app_bar_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

This is the fragment i want to implement:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsFragment" >
</fragment>
```

Comment: There are two separate styles - default in values folder and one in values-v21. Check if the app theme has same properties set in both. Mostly in the styles in values folder must have no appbar.